# Why guiminer is using different amount of GPU each time I restart my copmuter?

Tags: miner-configuration, gpu-mining, guiminer

Why guiminer is using different amount of GPU each time I restart my computer?
I'm running `guiminer-20121203`, `NVIDIA GeForce GTX 670M`, `poclbm.exe` with flags  `-s 0.005 -f 60`
What I noticed was, it was **35Mgash/s with 75% GPU usage**. And after I restart my computer, it became  **50Mgash/s with 100% GPU** usage with the same flag settings.

Also, before when I tried only with flag `-s 0.010` it utilized **100%** GPU, but without restarting computer, using flag `-s 0.011` reduced GPU usage to **60%**.

What's going on??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other applications can alter your GPU settings not just guiminer.

If you take a read over this question [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/4249/33) it may reflect a similar circumstance which is causing a variable hash rate on your hardware. Without knowing your exact usage of your computer though I cant say for sure.

Comment: I swear god I tested this, with exactly the same condition. Ok, just to be sure let's test this again... And.. I can't reproduce the situation I described above... Now same flags gives same hash rate and GPU usage. So I guess I was wrong.